# Coding normalization

Tags: logic

Working on a program that handles CNF (conjunctive normal form). If I have a formula like

(a iff b) where iff is if and only if. I'd like to know which one of the following options is the correct result:

1. (a implies b) and (b implies a), making the final result as (not a or b) and (not b or a)
2. a implies b and b implies a, in this case and has higher precedence and the result would be different (not sure what it will be)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the correct one.  "p iff q" means "(p → q) ∧ (q → p)".